# Delete Selected div in html

Tags: javascript, html

Here I m working on inbox page where I have to display mails.
There is a *`jsp`* code which get incremented when a new mail arrives in database.

I have put a delete button so that the selected mail can be deleted. But When I click the Del button whole Inbox is getting deleted due wrong placement of Function!

The code is (also at http://pastie.org/8593077):

```
<script>
function deleteCheckBox(){
  if (document.getElementById('checkboxid').checked){
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this checkbox?');
         if (answer)
           {
           $(".del_mail").remove();
           }
         }else{
           alert("Pls check the checkbox.");
          }
}
</script>

<form id ="login" name="login" action="" method="post" class="form">
                <div id="error"></div>              
                <fieldset>
                    <div><b>Inbox</b>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                <%
                    int i=0;
                    while(i<3)
                    {

                %>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="del_mail">
                            <section class="col col-16">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxid" name="checkboxname">
                            </section>

                            <section class="col col-6">
                                <label>
                                    <p>From</p>
                                </label>
                            </section>

                            <section class="col col-6">
                                <label>
                                    <a href="message.html">Subject</a>
                                </label>
                            </section>

                                <button align="right" id="btnDeleteid" onclick="deleteCheckBox()" name="btnDeletename">Delete</button>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                <% i++;
                    } %>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to ask **how to delete a specific row or Div here ?**

Comment: What do you mean "whole inbox"? Your del_mail div contains almost the entire inbox (without the title).

Comment: Never mind, I got this.

Comment: You are using the class selector for the jquery function, since the class is applied to all the rows, hence it will clear every row. You need to get a mechanism to differentiate the rows. And then pass the differentiation factor to the javascript function to get the required div.

Comment: Instead of removing with class, you should use ID for each row.

Comment: *"Are you sure you want to delete this checkbox"* you made my day!

Comment: @SurjithSM: yeah! i got your point. how to make dynamic id's as if there are 1000 mails how i iwll be able to generates dynamic id's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<button align="right" id="btnDeleteid" onclick="deleteCheckBox(this)" name="btnDeletename">Delete</button>
```

In the Above HTML you need to send the object of the current checkbox by using the this in the function.

And in the JS code use this:

```
function deleteCheckBox(that){
  if (that.checked){
     var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this checkbox?');
     if (answer) {
       that.parentNode.remove();
     }
  } else {
    alert("Pls check the checkbox.");
  }
}
```

And that object you can get in the parameter that I have taken as that. and by getting that you can select the parent node that you want to delete.

> In your code you are using the `.del_mail` which is selecting all the
>   elements which has the class name `del_mail` and deleting all those
>   elements.

Comment: @user3094320 use the code as I have post. this will use in the html part and that is used the JS part you can rename the that but only the that used in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a class ".del_mail" so *all* the divs of this class are deleted (the jquery call to remove actually loop on all such elements).

A solution that may work: you could put a different id, such as `id="del_mail_3"` based on your incremented variable and delete the right element `$("#del_mail_3")` by passing your `i` to `deletecheckbox`.

Answer (score -1):

Use below code, this will work (please add jquery library in your project)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".del_mail").click(function(){

     if (document.getElementById('checkboxid').checked){
        var answer = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this checkbox?');
        if (answer)
        {
          $(this).remove();
        }
         else{
           alert("Pls check the checkbox.");
        }
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: Adding jQuery is an option and I have given my answer on the top of it, if you don't like and please ignore but please don't down vote it.
We are here to help you

Comment: Come on, when you are selecting $(this).remove(); inside  $(".del_mail").click(function(){} , then it will only delete clicked item. and that's why "this" keyword represent

Comment: Man try the code you have proposed... here i have more than one mail... 

Functionality that i want is:
click Checkbox and then press Delete... then only the div is deleted.

Comment: I have modified the code according to your request which was not mentioned earlier in the problem statement given. Now try and let me know, if it does not work then it will not impact sice you have already downvoted